# Manually Trigger cellchange Event on Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-events

Is there a way to manually trigger the `cellchange` event on a datatable?

I'm using a custom datatable that allows a custom data type - a dropdown (combobox) - it's based on [this custom datatable](https://live.playg.app/play/picklist-in-lightning-datatable).

I have a couple of editable fields in each row, including the combobox. When I update a text field cell, I'm using an `oncellchange` handler to update the data in the datatable, and so when I do a `getSelectedRows()`, I can see the updated data. However, when I update the value of the combobox (select a value), I'm still updating the datatable data, but the `getSelectedRows()` doesn't include the updated combobox value. As soon as I edit another out-of-box input field **or** check/uncheck a row, **only then** does the `getSelectedRows()` return the updated data.

So my conclusion is that the `cellchange` and `rowselection` events are triggering something that internally updates the data returned by `getSelectedRows()`. And unfortunately this something does not happen when I update the combobox, which is a custom data type. So I'm trying to figure out how to do that.